# How to get messages for specific user?

Tags: android, vk

How to get incoming messages from specific user?

For example:

```
    VKRequest requestOutMessages = VKApi.messages().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, vkUserId));
    VKRequest requestInMessages = VKApi.messages().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OUT, vkUserId));
```

Which is giving me all 40 last messages from all my last conversations.

**EDIT**

```
public class VKApiMessagesExtension extends VKApiMessages {

    public VKRequest getHistory(VKParameters params) {
        return prepareRequest("getHistory", params, new VKParser() {
            @Override
            public Object createModel(JSONObject object) {
                 return new VKApiGetMessagesResponse(object);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Messages in VK can only be accessed by the user involved in the conversation. If you use the VK API to get messages, they will be for the logged in user.

In other words, messages are private.

[The documentation](http://vk.com/dev/messages.get) states that "Returns a list of the current user's incoming or outgoing private messages."

Comment: messages.get gives only all last messages. For me the solution was is just extending VKApiMessages class and implementing messages.getHistory method. Which is actually returns all history that i wanted. It's sad that most of methods must be implemented manually and they are not inside Android VK Api.

Comment: @Outofdate Hello, can You please write here some code of how you have extended getHistory? Because I also have this problem, but I am ne in java ><

Comment: @vladimir added example, try it, is that enough?

Comment: @Outofdate Thanx, I will change my code based on your example!